# Adobe Captivate - must view all sub-slides before continuing

Tags: actionscript, adobe-captivate

I am using Adobe Captivate to create an online learning course.

An abbreviation is broken down into 6 buttons, each with an action to bring you to their respective slides. Once the slide is complete, you are brought back to the original.

The ask: the original slide with the abbreviation should only display a 'continue' button once the user has visited all 6 slides.

Is there a way to do this with ActionScript?

Comment: AFAIK (and my husband is on the advisory committe for Captivate), you can't directly use Actionscript in Captivate. You have to use "[Advanced Actions](http://lilybiri.posterous.com/tag/advancedactions)" instead

Comment: So these advanced actions are just limited Actionscript functions? Do you think this functionality is just not doable?

Comment: It's doable, but not with Actionscript. Go ask on the Captivate forum at forums.adobe.com. I could have once told you how to do this off the top of my head, but not today.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide or show buttons in Captivate. You can also change whether or not they are shown using Advanced Actions (you'd probably need to use the conditional actions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ActionScript, but there's an easy way to do this using the Advanced Actions in Captivate. Here's how I would approach it. First, create six variables, one for each of the six respective slides, so you could create variables called v_slide1_viewed, v_slide2_viewed, v_slide3_viewed, v_slide4_viewed, v_slide5_viewed, and v_slide6_viewed. Set their default values equal to 0 (I usually prefix my variables with v_ to distinguish from the inbuilt Captivate variables).

Now on slide 1, set an **On Enter** property to assign the value 1 to the variable v_slide1_viewed. This means, that when slide 1 loads, the variable 'v_slide1_viewed' will be set to 1. Similarly do this for each of the six respective slides.

Now on the abbreviation slide, create a SmartShape (Continue) button and uncheck the 'Visible in Output' so that by default this button is not displayed. Now you can write an advanced actions (conditional) script that says if

```
v_slide1_viewed = 1 AND 
v_slide1_viewed = 2 AND 
v_slide1_viewed = 3 AND 
v_slide1_viewed = 4 AND 
v_slide1_viewed = 5 AND 
v_slide1_viewed = 6
```

Then Show and select the smartshape ID or whatever you named that object.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

-Sean